# how can i get slower animaton in css scale?

Tags: css, scale

I wrote this code for animate my menu

```
   .main-navigation a:hover{
        transform: scale(1.1)!important;
```

but I want slower animation with time or anything else

Comment: Can you please take the take to craft a more descriptive question. There isn't much to go on here and "slower" is not very precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
.main-navigation a {
    transition: transform 250ms;
    transform-origin: center center;
}
.main-navigation a:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1) !important;
}
```

A friendly advice: try to setup your CSS so you don't ever have to use `!important`.

Comment: .main-navigation a {
    transition: transform 250ms !important;
    transform-origin: center center;
}
.main-navigation a:hover{
    transform: scale(1.3) !important;
}

Comment: this worked and this isnt my css im overridding on a theme

Answer (score 2):

Add `transition: 0.3s` (or any other time you want).

Comment: Add it not on `:hover` state, but on the basic `.main-navigation a`.